# Python Selenium Click on all li

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

as I click on a

inside it there is an  and inside the  there is an  I had already tried to use:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"result-view").click();
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"result-view").click();
```

but no it worked and in the logs it appeared that only the image is clickable.

```
 Message: element click intercepted: Element <li class="result-visualizar">...</li> is not clickable at point (130, 939). Other element would receive the click: <img src="../resources/image/icone-visualizar.png" title="Visualizar Dados">
```

Note, I want to click all the buttons that are on the page but it didn't click even the first one

[image]

Comment: You can try element=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"result-view") then driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Comment: In your code trial you are tring to click on `<... class="result-view">` but error says the element is `<li class="result-visualizar">...</li>`